# Chain Rule $y=\frac{1}{t^2+3t-1}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have to take the derivative of:

> $$y=\frac{1}{t^2+3t-1}$$

The answer I got is:

> $$y'=\frac{-2t-3}{(t^2+3t-1)^2}$$

I had to use chain rule to find the derivative, and I wondering how would I identify the inner and outer function?

I identified:

## Outer Function

> $$f(u)=\frac{1}{u}$$

that would entail that the derivative of $f(u)$ is $\frac{-1}{u^2}$ the inner function being

## Inner Function

> $$u=t^2+3t-1$$

### Overall Question

Did I identify the inner function, and the outer function correctly since I used quotient rule to get the my answer not chain rule because I was a bit lost on the function identification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the quotient rule was also fine here, but you identified the outer and inner functions correctly. The identification process just gets down to understanding what operations you do first.

In your case you start by performing the operations to find the denominator. Only then you do the division. Hence the function in the denominator is the inner function because it is naturally the sub-result you calculate first.

Comment: +1 Sorry I changed my question because I found an even harder problem.But thanks for your answer.

Comment: Your answer still applies thanks.

Comment: @EnlightenedFunky noticed that. Changed it to be a more general answer.